# Index Match and Summing Values

Tags: google-sheets

***Edit with real data

[Pay Stub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CfVt.png)

[Hours worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMZl7.png)

I edited my original question to now consider my actual sheet. The driver's name is in cell J5 on the sheet in the first image. The hours are on a separate sheet (same workbook) shown in the second image. I want to match the name in J5 to any entries that appear in the second image and total each daily hour count and put it in the respective cell on the first sheet. For example,  Hazem's Sunday total would go in cell B11 on the first sheet and then continue.

Comment: Also, sometimes a name does not appear in both "tables". For example, Dave can show up in the left table only. So the sum should only contain the value from the left table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case:

```
=ArrayFormula(
IFNA(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A11:A,A11:A<>""),A1:H6,SEQUENCE(1,7,2),0))+
IFNA(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A11:A,A11:A<>""),J1:Q7,SEQUENCE(1,7,2),0)))
```

You'll have to replace the `A1:H6` and `J1:Q7` if you want to change your tables though. If you move your Totals table, you'll have to replace the `A11:A` as well.

To make your life easier, you can use Named Ranges to name your tables.

Comment: Hello, thank  you so much for your response. I tried applying the formula you provided to my actual sheet and I was having trouble getting it to work. I edited my question to provide my actual google sheets. I changed the respective ranges and such from your formula but I am getting REF errors. Thanks!!!

Comment: I also wanted to point out that drivers can also appear in the two tables more than one time. See Jarius Fair comes up twice in the right table. Thanks again.